# C# Fields Capitalization Convention

Tags: c#

My textbook (Visual C# How to Program, 6/e) states that fields in C# should use camelCase. This corresponds with examples given in Microsoft C# Guide:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields

```cs
public class CalendarEntry
{
    // private field
    private DateTime date;
    // ...
}
```

However the official Microsoft naming convention clearly states that fields should use PascalCase (although they didn't provide an example of private fields as they normaly should be):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions

Identifier: Field,
Casing: Pascal,
Example:

```cs
class MessageQueue
{
    public static readonly TimeSpan InfiniteTimeout;
}

public struct UInt32
{
    public const Min = 0;
}
```

Sooo, how do I know what case to use to keep my coding style right according to MS coding conventions?

Comment: Pascal case for Classes, Methods, global variables. camelCase for local variables.

Comment: Well... if you want to keep it "correct" as far as MS is concerned, follow their guidelines of course. Although you'll probably notice that the conventions change over time and will even find plenty of examples where they don't follow their own.

Comment: Nowadays for private fields a lot of us, most of us I hope, use underscore-prefixed `_camelCase`. It's too easy to mistype `value` for `Value` when it's a backing field for a property with a setter (that `date`/`Date` example is objectively not very good practice, no matter who recommended it). For public static const or readonly fields use `PascalCase`. Public vs private is a big difference.

Comment: I too prefer the underscore on my fields, but I think using the phrase "we" here is quite misleading or confusing. You certainly will not find advocacy for its usage in the Framework Design Guidelines -- in fact, you will find the entire notion of prefixes on field names to be discouraged. That being said, I've been using it since I started in 1.1 and I have no intention of stopping ;)

Comment: @Trioj Maybe I've just seen it a lot in WPF code from people who know what they're doing. With intellisense being case-blind, I think it's arguably a good idea.

Comment: There is no contradiction in MS conventions you’ve quoted. Private fields are camel cased, non private fields are Pascal cased. Where things get funky is with methods/properties; the private/non private distinction doesn’t hold and you’ll see all kind of counter examples in MS docs

Comment: @EdPlunkett I've seen it all over the place in lots of different apps, throughout the years. I truly do prefer it myself and it has added benefits like you mentioned that protect against typos as well as making minor annoyances like public Thing(int value) { this.value = value; } unnecessary. On a personal level, it is a naming convention that I picked up from my mentor when I first started in C#.

Comment: I knew that this question would cost me reputation, but I got the answers I needed, so thank you all for sharing the experience. :)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

AFAIK there is no *set in stone* convention for `c#`... Yes, there is *technically* an *"official"* convention, but it's not followed 100% of the time, even in MS's own source code, and it's certainly not religiously followed by many programmers and/or companies.

With that in mind, my preferred convention, and the best I've seen so far, is the one set by default in ReSharper. I strongly suggest following this convention:

- **PascalCase** for: Classes, Structs, Methods, Properties, `public | internal | protected` Fields (regardless of `static | readonly | const`) and `private const` Fields.
- **_underscorePrefixCamelCase** for: `private` _fields (except when `const`).
- **camelCase** for: *local* variables.

Comment: @Servy A bit off-topic, but since you apparently know this stuff, can you explain me what the distinction is? The semantics of `field VS variable` seem to be all over the place, depending on who one asks.

Comment: A field is a "member variable", as it were. Local variables in methods are not fields. I'm not aware of any `local` keyword in C#.

Comment: [Here's the top google result](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields), which is of course correct (by definition, as it's the documentation for the language, so what it says the definition is is what the definition is).  Reading through various other top results, I don't see anything that contradicts it.