# Why should protected data member fields be capitalized?

Tags: c#, refactoring, resharper

While moving private field members into base classes and changing their access to protected, ReSharper suggests that they be capitalized.

So, after changing

```
 protected bool _isSuccess;
```

to

```
 protected bool IsSuccess;
```

no more notifications are given, implying correctness.

**Should this field be converted to a property, since it's uppercase format suggested that it is one?**

Comment: Pretty much opinion based. Not everything ReSharper suggests is best practice. And best practice is often opinion based, too ...

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46777544/c-sharp-fields-capitalization-convention)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Fields Capitalization Convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46777544/c-sharp-fields-capitalization-convention)

Comment: I think ReSharper prefers the `_variable` for private fields only. Anything you could potentially access from a derived class it probably wants you to really use a property. I tend to agree, but again, very much your choice.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ That is what I had in mind, and it would provide the get/set abstraction wrapper, however the field naming convention I think is also a good indicator that it is in fact a non-public member (field). Though, I then got wondering if private properties are common (I never use them), so again became unsure.

Comment: I don't use private properties much; more often it's something like `protected bool IsSuccess { get; private set; }`, so it's basically read-only to derived classes.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ Good point (overlooked that option, I see, then just open write access on an as-needed basis). There are also readonly fields, but they are more restrictive so may not suffice in all the same cases. I guess then with this convention, fields are strictly scoped to their immediate class only (no subclasses). Works for me.

Comment: `protected bool IsSuccess { get; }` is sufficient for setting/writing from the constructor only (most restrictive apparently).